# Why is the setting "Owners who can assign members as group owners in Azure portals" only available in some Azure AD tenants?

Tags: azure-active-directory

The setting "Owners who can assign members as group owners in Azure portals" in Azure portal at  AAD -> General -> Groups, only appears in some AAD Tenants.

Some examples that led me to this conclusion:

- An organization owns two tenants (both licensed with P2) and in one tenant the option appears (for both M365 and Security groups) and in the other it doesn't appear.
- In both my lab Azure AD tenants (one P2 and other P1) the option simply doesn't appear.
- In another company corporate tenant that option is only available for Security Groups but not for Microsoft 365 groups.

So, my questions are:

- Why these settings appear in some tenants and not in others?
- Is this configurable?

Answer (score 0):

we are working to deprecate the current owner setting on Azure portal, as it is a UX-only control (Azure Admin portal and Access Panel groups portal) and it has caused a lot of confusion among customers. The setting is not available for tenants that didn't have the setting configured. Those that have the setting configured can still see the setting.

The new setting to define owner policy will be available soon (hopefully early next year) and will control owner behavior on the API level across Microsoft services. We hope you will find the new setting more effective than the UX-only control.

Comment: Who is "we" here?